# Fill dropdown column with possibilities

Tags: smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I have code where I'm retrieving values from another program and putting them into a Smartsheet.  One of the columns is a dropdown where I want specific possiblities.

Is there a way in the C# API to programmatically set the possibilities of a Smartsheet dropdown column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see the documentation for Columns: http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#columns

In particular, the code example for [Update Column](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#update-column) shows how you set the column options:

```
Column column = new Column.UpdateColumnBuilder(columnId, "First Column", 0)
    .SetType(ColumnType.PICKLIST)
    .SetOptions(new string[] { "One", "Two" })
    .Build();
smartsheet.SheetResources.ColumnResources.UpdateColumn(sheetId, column);
```